# jQuery create loop with animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to slide a div to the right and have it loop. Below is my code a link to the jsfiddle:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>animate demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    background-color: #bca;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="block">Hello!</div>

<script>
function scroll() {
    $( "#block" ).animate({marginLeft: "0.6in"}, 
    {
        duration: 1500,
        complete: function() {
            scroll
        }
    }
)};
scroll();
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZWSPJ/

Comment: You need to reset your `margin-left` to 0 at the start of your function if you want a repeating animation.

Comment: Are you trying to make a marquee type scroll (where it runs off the right edge and runs back on at the left edge), should it just jump back to 0 and start again or should it forever move to the right?

Comment: The answer by adeneo should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update:

I appreciate the accept, but adeneo's answer was so much more elegant. As he removed it, I am going to include his approach for the rotation here: [Live demo (click).](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWSPJ/7/)

```
var $block = $('#block'); //I like to cache my references in advance

var flag = 0;
(function scroll() { //auto call this function with an IIFE
  $block.animate({marginLeft: (flag) ? 0 : '0.6in'}, 1500, scroll);
  flag ^= 1; //reverse flag
}());
```

#### Other approaches:

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWSPJ/3/)

```
var $block = $('#block'); //you can go ahead and cache this reference
function scroll() {
  $block.css('marginLeft', 0); //reset margin
  $block.animate({marginLeft: "0.6in"}, //animate margin
  {
    duration: 1500,
    complete: function() {
      scroll(); //repeat
    }
  }
)};
scroll(); //call function to begin loop
```

In case you're looking to reverse the animation on each run, you could do this:

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWSPJ/6/)

```
var $block = $('#block'); //you can go ahead and cache this reference

var animSwitch = 0;
function scroll() {
  var margin = 0;
  if (!animSwitch) {
    margin = '0.6in';
    animSwitch = 1;
  }
  else {
    animSwitch = 0;
  }
  $block.animate({marginLeft: margin}, //animate margin
    {
      duration: 1500,
      complete: function() {
        scroll(); //repeat
      }
    }
  )
};
scroll(); //call function to begin loop
```

Answer (score 2):

So one correct answer is:

```
function scroll() {
    $( "#block" ).animate({marginLeft: "+=0.6in"}, 
    {
        duration: 1500,
        complete: scroll
    }
)};
scroll();
```

Answer (score 1):

do you want something like this ?

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/FaE39/)</kbd>

```
function scroll() {
    $("#block").animate({
        marginLeft: "+=0.6in"
    }, {
        duration: 1500,
        complete:scroll
    })
};
scroll();
```

Answer (score 0):

part of your problem is

```
complete: function() {
    scroll
}
```

this wont call the scroll function, just the wrapping function. You would need to do:

```
complete: function() {
    scroll();
}
```

or neater

```
complete : scroll
```

Comment: yes your right m59 - just to clarify, this only why the script wasnt looping at all, it doesnt address the whole issue. see other other answers for a more complete response to the question ( that i didnt read properly, long day :) )